# serif vs 'serif' in Chrome, Linux Mint

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, typography

I'm not sure of this affects other versions of Chrome, I'm using Linux Mint 12 right now.

It seems that font-family `serif` vs `"serif"` (with quotes) displays a slightly larger font?

I just thought it was weird, I couldn't figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated, though this is def. low priority.

Thanks!

Comment: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/efQr7/2/). Looks the same to me on my Chrome, Windows 7.

Comment: Are you sure it is just larger? Isn't it sans-serif? As it does not recognize `"serif"` as a font, it falls backs to something not serif.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Generic font family names aren't supposed to be quoted](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#value-def-generic-family) as they are considered keywords, not strings.

My guess is that either:

- Linux Mint contains a font family called "serif", which Chrome is using when you quote the name as a string in your CSS; or
- It *doesn't* contain such a font, in which case Chrome falls back to some other system font that can either be the default serif font assigned to the browser or something else entirely.

It does not *directly* fall back to that default serif font *solely based on the word "serif"*. In other words, it's not interpreted the same as the unquoted keyword `serif`.